# Regexp to match 3 '+' characters anywhere in the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I've tried to form a Javascript regular expression to find exactly three matches of '+' characters anywhere in the string. They can be adjacent of shuffled.

I came up with this but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

```
^.*(?:\+{3}).*$
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `^.*(?:\+{3}).*$` regex matches a line (string with no line breaks) that has 3 consecutive `+` symbols.

To match any *string* having just 3 plus symbols you may use

```
/^(?:[^+]*\+){3}[^+]*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/omcuf7/1)

**Details**:

- `^`  - start of string
- `(?:[^+]*\+){3}`  - exactly 3 sequences of:

  - `[^+]*` - zero or more chars other than `+`
  - `\+` - a `+` symbol
- `[^+]*` - zero or more chars other than `+`
- `$` - end of string.

```js
var ss = [ "+1111+", "++++", "11+111+111+111", "222+222++222+"]; // Test strings
var rx = /^(?:[^+]*\+){3}[^+]*$/;
for (var s = 0; s < ss.length; s++) {                  // Demo
  document.body.innerHTML += "Testing \"<i>" + ss[s] + "</i>\"... ";
  document.body.innerHTML += "Matched: <b>" + rx.test(ss[s]) + "</b><br/>";
}
```

Comment: You may make it more customizable with `var rx = RegExp("^(?:[^+]*\\+){" + num + "}[^+]*$")`.

Comment: Works like a charm. I tried it without the slashes at the beginning and the end of the string. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply check if the number of `+` matches are 3?

For example

```
var matches = "asd+asd+asd+asd".match(/\+/g);
var isValid = matches && matches.length == 3;
```

Comment: _"Why not simply check if the number of + matches are more than 3?"_ Because that's not the requirement.

Comment: Actually, OP needs to detect strings that contain *exactly* 3 pluses.

Comment: So could you just change the inequality to an equals?

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to have the regex itself check whether the string contains three `+`es (rather than something like gurvinder has where the code is checking information about the result), then you can use this:

```js
var reg = /^[^+]*\+[^+]*\+[^+]*\+[^+]*$/;

console.log(reg.test('+++'));
console.log(reg.test('a++a+'));
console.log(reg.test('+a+'));
console.log(reg.test('+++a+a'));
```